# HealthKit steps delay

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am using HealthKit to show steps in my app, but it is very delay. I am using other apps that shows in real-time the steps, but feels like HealtKit has a few minutes delay?

This is the code to receive steps:

```
func queryStepsSum() {
        let sumOption = HKStatisticsOptions.cumulativeSum
        let startDate = NSDate().dateByRemovingTime()
        let endDate = NSDate()
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate as Date, end: endDate as Date, options: [])
        let statisticsSumQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: healthKitManager.stepsCount!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: sumOption) { [unowned self] (query, result, error) in
            if (result != nil) {
                if let sumQuantity = result?.sumQuantity() {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let numberOfSteps = Int(sumQuantity.doubleValue(for: self.healthKitManager.stepsUnit))
                        self.stepsLabel.text = "\(numberOfSteps)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        healthKitManager.healthStore?.execute(statisticsSumQuery)
    }
```

Any tips?

Comment: Use CMPedometer instead?

Comment: @matt Can you provide an example to get steps using CMPedometer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` with the `updateHandler` property set. Executing a long-running query will indicate to HealthKit that your app intends to display live results to the user.